# How can I access user-installed keys and certificates from my Android app?

Tags: android, key, x509certificate

I've been struggling to consume user installed identity CA certs from a p12 file on an SD card.  The certs and keys are installed using the Secure Credential Storage (Location & Security > Install from SD card).

I haven't found any documentation stating the location if the keys and certificates once imported.  I tried to create an instance of a TrustManagerFactory with no luck, it just contained all the pre-installed SSL certificates.

Creating an KeyStore with the default parameters doesn't seem to work either.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [JavaMail Crypto](http://javamail-crypto.sourceforge.net/) and [Bouncy Castle](http://bouncycastle.org) combo.

They allow you to import the p12 file using a file input stream and let you deal with it accordingly.

It can be tricky to get set up and if you get frustrated, there is a 30 day free trial with [Chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatAndroid.asp) developed specifically for android which I can confirm works perfectly.